# Logstash -- delimit event in log4net.log which may contain multiple lines

Tags: logstash, logstash-file

[image]

Here is a typical log file generated from log4net

So, this log file is read by the [logstash file input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html).

By default, the `delimiter` in configuration is `\n`, which means each line is an event.

But in the log file above, you can see there could be multiple lines for one event. (like ERROR or FAULT or others)

**How to configure Logstash to delimit the event correctly?**

I suppose I could configure multiple delimiters like `\nINFO` `\nDEBUG` `\nERROR` `\nFAULT` .  But the [document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html) says there can only be one delimiter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following config should delimit your events properly.

**Input config:**

```
input { 
    file {
        path => "/absolute/path/here.log"
        type => "log4net"
        codec => multiline {
                    pattern => "^(DEBUG|WARN|ERROR|INFO|FATAL)"
                    negate => true
                    what => previous
                }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you have there is a multiline event.  There is a [codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html) that will help you process that.

The basic idea is to define a pattern that identifies the beginning of a log entry (in your case, the log level), and then roll all other lines into the previous one.

Comment: Right answer. I've just added an example config.

Comment: Someone edited this answer as it seems the multiline filter was removed in LS5.  Since I know lots of people are running older versions, I'll just add that option here as a comment.